# Zebra printing image using GraphicsUtil

Tags: android, zebra-printers

I am trying to print a single image to a zebra printer from android.

List of things i already tried(not exactly in this order).zp is a ZebraPrinter,zpc is a ZebraPrinterConnection

Version 1 - prints blank (however the height seems to be correct)

```
     zpc.write("! U1 JOURNAL \r\n U1 SETFF 50 2 \r\n");
     zp.getGraphicsUtil().printImage(bmp,0,0,-1,-1,false);
```

Version 2 - prints blank (however the height seems to be correct)

```
     zpc.getToolsUtil.sendCommand("! U1 JOURNAL \r\n U1 SETFF 50 2 \r\n");
     zp.getGraphicsUtil().printImage(bmp,0,0,-1,-1,false);
```

Version 3 -prints image followed by a lot of empty space,there are no issues with the image in this case it looks great

```
     zp.getGraphicsUtil().printImage(bmp,0,0,-1,-1,false);
```

Notes:

1.tried ZPL,the printer language isn't ZPL,its probably CPCL(which is unknown to me)

2.text files print ok,so the printer's working fine

Comment: Did you find any solution?i am facing the same problem of empty space after the image?

Answer (score 2):

To remove extra space Use the code as

```
zpc.write("! UTILITIES\r\nIN-MILLIMETERS\r\nSETFF 10 2\r\nPRINT\r\n".getBytes());
zp.getGraphicsUtil().printImage(bmp,0,0,100,100,false);
```

where 4th and 5th parameter can be as you required ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please be sure to read the helpful formatting guide that appears when you click the large orange question mark in the post editor.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want the image to print correctly but not have the extra whitespace at the end, correct?

If that's what you want, then your `SETFF` command needs to be fixed. You need to send down something like this (see the CPCL manual for more options of the SETFF command:

```
! UTILITIES
IN-MILLIMETERS
SETFF 50 2
PRINT
```

The code would look something like this :

```
zpc.write("! UTILITIES\r\nIN-MILLIMETERS\r\nSETFF 10 2\r\nPRINT\r\n".getBytes());
zp.getGraphicsUtil().printImage(bmp,0,0,-1,-1,false);
```

Comment: Does it also feed lots of paper after the print job?

Comment: what kind of media do you have? Black mark? Gap? Label or receipt? Check your media setting SGDs.  ! U1 getvar "media.sense_mode" and ! U1 getvar "media.type"

Comment: Hey, I am facing the same issue of printing some inches after the black mark is found on paper. I am using commands `! DF CONFIG.SYS                        
! UTILITIES                                    
BAR-SENSE
LABEL                                     
PRINT` Any help ?